# Firefox won't show page when PHP sends a 408-header

Tags: php, firefox

There are some times when I'd like my site to trigger a 408-response (for when various pieces aren't responsive). (PHP 5.3.3 and Apache, both Windows and Linux machines)

I can use the following code and get the expected result in all browsers except Firefox:

```
<?php
// Access forbidden:
header('HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout',true,408);
echo 'hi';exit;
```

But Firefox just immediately sends the "The connection was reset" page, and Firebug shows it got the 408 message. Is this by design in Firefox, or is there some way around this?

Comment: A 408 is generally intended when the client (browser) has sent an incomplete request or response, not for when the server is taking too long.  This misinterpretation may be confusing Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 408 response is the server telling the client that the *client* didn't send all the details for a request within the time that the server was willing to wait, and that the server has forcefully closed the connection.

So, yes, this is by design in Firefox.

Edit: Consider using the `503 Service Unavailable` temporary error code instead, possibly with a `Retry-After` header.  I've never tested to see if the `Retry-After` works.

Comment: I'm not sure this means that Firefox shouldn't look at the body of the 408 response (and display it instead of its built in error page, as it does with a 404 error), but the 503 is a good suggestion.

Comment: @userx: I haven't checked the Firefox source, but I believe Firefox treats the connection as if it were bad in both directions, and thus assumes the 408 response body will not be a complete response.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Perhaps... there are other ways that a client can check a response body (such as a Content-Length header) to check if it is complete (and hence might convince Firefox to show the body?). I haven't checked the FF source either, so this is purely a guess